# Get objects from a NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, json, nsdictionary

I get from an URL this result :

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

it looks like this :

```
  [{"modele":"Audi TT Coup\u00e9 2.0 TFSI","modele_annee":null,"annee":"2007","cilindre":"4 cyl","boite":"BVM","transmision":"Traction","carburant":"ES"},
{"modele":"Audi TT Coup\u00e9 2.0 TFSI","modele_annee":null,"annee":"2007","cilindre":"4 cyl","boite":"BVM","transmision":"Traction","carburant":"ES"}]
```

So it contains 2 dictionaries. I need to take the objects from all the keys from this result. How can I do this?

I tried this : `NSDictionary vehiculesPossedeDictionary=(NSDictionary *)result;`

and then this : `[vehiculesPossedeDictinary objectForKey:@"modele"];` but this is not working.

Please help me...  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a JSON string which describes an "array" containing two "objects".  This needs to be converted to Objective-C objects using a JSON parser, and when converted will be an NSArray containing two NSDictionarys.

Comment: I have done this....now I have a NSArray containing 2 NSDictionary...for this I need help,I don't know to obtain the objects

Comment: You index the array (objectForIndex) to extract one dictionary, then find the element you want in that dictionary (objectForKey).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to be able to get your dictionary directly from a string of JSON.  You are going to have to going to have to run it through a JSON parser first.

At this point, there is not one build into the iOS SDK, so you will have to download a third-party tool and include it in your project.

There are a number of different JSON parser, include TouchJSON, YAJL, etc. that you can find and compare.  Personally, I am using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit).

Comment: I have done this...I sad that ...now I have a NSArray containing 2 NSDictionary...for this I need help,I don't know to obtain the objects

Comment: If you have an array named "array", you can get the first dictionary with NSDictionary *firstDict = [array objectAtIndex:0] and the second with NSDictionary *secondDict = [array objectAtIndex:1];  Then you can get, for example, the transmission of the first dictionary with NSString *transmission = [firstDictionary objectForKey:@"transmission"];

Answer (score 1):

@MatthewGillingham suggests JSONKit. I imagine it does fine, but I've always used its competitor [json-framework](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/&ei=_e2OTu_XJom4tgeD9oSpDA&usg=AFQjCNHpLrWFTsmjeJnI7zslG9sx-w04uQ&sig2=rD8BicHmTnCGipmbKOkfRQ). No real reason, I just found it first and learned it first. I do think its interface is somewhat simpler, but plenty of people do fine with JSONKit too.

Using json-framework:

```
require JSON.h
```

...and then

```
NSString *myJsonString = @"[{'whatever': 'this contains'}, {'whatever', 'more content'}]";

NSArray *data = [myJsonString JSONValue];

foreach (NSDictionary *item in data) {
    NSString *val = [item objectForKey:@"whatever"];
    //val will contain "this contains" on the first time through
    //this loop, then "more content" the second time.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have array of dictionary just assign objects in array to dictionary like

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndes:0];
```

and then use this dictionary to get values.